# Shift Register Output tidied up by capacitor over a length of Cat5. What is happening?

Tags: shift-register, distance

I was hoping someone could explain to me what is happening to my project. Initially I had an HD44780 Driven LCD positioned close to the 74HC595 Shift Register controlling it, but in the most recent iteration of my project I've deemed it necessary to move the LCD to another location. Im testing at the moment by having the two IC's conneceted over a 1m (approx) stretch of Cat5 cable.

In my code the LCD initialises, then prints 0123. Waits 2 seconds then prints "Hello World!" character by character. When the LCD was close to the Shift Register this worked no problem, but when on the other end of the Cat 5 cable. 0123 are printed fine but "Hello World!" is typed with different characters all together (Japanese Symbols, "V" and whitespace).

I later added a 100nF capacitor to each "bit" close to the LCD and the printout is now fine.

So my question to you is, how and why has adding the caps allowed the Data High and Low's to "clean up" and represent themeselves to the LCD correctly? Is there something I could do better (apart from  a redesign).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fReBRa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of hard to guess from here, but your longer cabling probably was just picking up RF energy, and thus, high-frequency noise. The rather large capacitors are effectively shorting that noise to ground. Maybe you should use smaller capacitors and also some termination resistors close to the "receiving" pins.

Typically, I'd try to get one rather nicely shielded data+clock line (maybe, even differential) from whatever feeds the shift register to the display – and place the shift register close to the display driver.

Personally, I'd consider just getting a small microcontroller to directly put next to the display, and make that MCU receive data to be displayed – e.g. via UART, SPI or I²C, all of which are commonly found in MCU hardware – and directly talk to the display driver. Sure, a 74xx595 is probably cheaper than a microcontroller, but in my experience, displays are often mounted close to further user interface elements (LEDs, display background light, buttons and knobs), and it might be well worth spending 40ct – 1.50€ on a MCU that handles all that in one place, leaving only the business-logic relevant communication to be done over the long link. (cabling isn't free, either)

Comment: 100nF is large?

What kind of resistor do you think I would need to further improve this if I was to "terminate" as you say.

The display and other interface elements were initially above the perfboard that sits the MCU and Shift Register, but I Had to move it as I took my project apart and rebuilt it from bits and bobs. The shift register and MCU are soldered to one another in close proximity so separating the two woudl be horrible.